# CakePHP Associations Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp, associations

I think I have a quiet simple error but i can't solve it... I try to associate two tables:

- projects hasMany keywords
- keywords belogsTo projects

My code:

```
<?php
class KeywordsController extends AppController{
    public function add(){
        $projects = $this->Keyword->Project->find('list'); //***here is the error***
        //pr($projects);

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Keyword->save($this->request->data);
            $this->redirect('/keywords');   
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php
class ProjectsController extends AppController{
    public function add(){
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Project->save($this->request->data);
            $this->redirect('/projects');   
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php
class Project extends AppModel{
    public $hasMany = 'Keyword';
}
```

---

```
<?php
class Keyword extends AppModel{
    public $belongsTo = 'Project';

}
```

Error message:

> Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object 
> File:
>   /Users/me/Localhost/cakephp/app/Controller/KeywordsController.php
>   Line: 7

Comment: @DipeshParmar You don't need (and really should not add for convention based ones!) the $name properties in CakePHP >= 2.0. App::uses() statements, though, are very important and missing here.

Comment: @mark Yes I know i provided complete solution to OP and OP has accepted answer too see below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add below line above the class declaration for models.

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
```

also define `name` property for class definition.

```
public $name = 'Project';
public $name = 'Keyword';
```

**For Project Model**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Project extends AppModel{
    public $name = 'Project';
    public $hasMany = 'Keyword';
}
```

**For Keyword Model**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Keyword extends AppModel{
    public $name = 'Keyword';
    public $belongsTo = 'Project';

}
```

**Edit**

```
$this->loadModel('Project');
$projects = $this->Project->find('list');
```

Comment: yes, I forgot about it. Where do I put these in? Im still a bit confused about cakephp

Comment: Setting the $name property is not necessary, it is automatically set to the class name: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#name